# I hope that there is somewhere I can ask where I should ask my question, is there something like this?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

After stackoverflow team launched their other websites through area51, some times I face a problem while trying to ask a question "on which website should i ask this question".

For example I wanted to ask about a service to allow users to pay to my website and i can just integrate in my website easily. I got confused, should i ask on webapps, money, or stackoverflow, or should i ask on all?

Is there a way to take advice about where to ask my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted to ask about a service to allow users to pay to my website and i can just integrate in my website easily.

That sounds like a question for the [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site since it's about the operation of a site that you control.  Once you select a service you can probably ask specific questions about programming with it on Stack Overflow.

> on which website should i ask this question.

I usually go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and browse the list of sites in public beta, then go to the [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) for a site that I think will be appropriate.  They all have a "What kind of questions can I ask here?" section at the top.

I'm not sure if we've established a place where you can ask others where they'd ask a question other than here on Meta. (Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.)  If you have enough reputation, you might try asking in one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/).